# Seaborn tiem series plot

Tags: time, seaborn

I am using tsplot to plot a time series. The date filed yyy-mm-dd is the index for my data frame. The plot does not show dates instead it just shows numerals. How can i fix this

Comment: `tsplot` is not useful to plot timeseries (despite the confusing name). That's why it has been replaced in newer versions of seaborn anyways. Use a seaborn lineplot or a matplotlib plot instead.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am using seaborn "relplot" but the x axis date labels are so close it is not possible to see anything. This there a way to space them out